# How to add short cut of my app in my app's widget menu

Tags: android, widget, android-shortcut

I want to add my app's shortcut into my app's widget menu. how to add it?
I can't find a solution for this, maybe my searching key is wrong. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can configure your widget to open your app when widget's top header is clicked. Is this what you want? Or you want to show your app's icon on widget top header and bind on click to that?

Comment: the second one i want @Deepesh

Comment: do you know how to show your apps icon on widget?

Comment: @Vji provide a sample image or explain a bit what exactly you want

Answer (score 0):

In order to bind click listener to any icon shown on your widget header, you can do it by following:

Add these codes in `onUpdate()` method of your widget provider:

```
// Create an intent
Intent openMyAppIntent= new Intent(context, ActivityToBeOpened.class);

// Create pending intent with intent created above
PendingIntent openMyAppPendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, openMyAppIntent, 0);

// Bind pending intent with your remote view OnClickPendingIntent method
remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.app_icon_on_widget, openMyAppPendingIntent);
```